# Apache2 Basic Auth: user@ip, user2@ip2 - Is this possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost, authentication, httpd.conf

I am looking at running an external service for clients to use here in my office while clients are working remotely at their office.

Assumptions: Both my office IP and clients office IP are static.

I wish to allow access to a service, for example an HTTP Basic Auth secured administration application, to my clients.

Is there a way in Apache Basic Auth or otherwise to create User @ IP based restrictions?

I would like:

- me @ my_office
- me @ my_home
- client1 @ their_office1
- client2 @ their_office2

For testing, I have attempted this code:

```
<Location />
    Satisfy All

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorisation"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.1/32
    Require user me

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.2/32
    Require user client1
</Location>
```

- Testing with [me@10.0.0.1] allowed access, success.
- Testing with [client1@10.0.0.1] allowed access, fail.
- Testing with [client2@10.0.0.1] dis-allowed access, success (client2 is in htpasswd file, but not specified in Require User).

Is there a known way of doing this using Apache Basic Auth?

Also, instead of receiving a "Forbidden" for a successful user/password from an unknown IP, is it possible to ask Apache to request the user details again?

Comment: If this cannot be achieved, there is another solution: 
Run multiple virtualhosts, one per client, each with their own IP and Basic Auth restrictions. Maybe this would be cleaner?
This would look like: client1.service.example.com, client2.service.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache httpd 2.4, you can use the new ,  syntax to accomplish this.

```
<RequireAny>

<RequireAll>
  Require IP 10.0.0.1/32
  Require user me
</RequireAll>

<RequireAll>
  Require IP 10.0.0.2/32
  Require user client1
</RequireAll>

</RequireAny>
```

This kind of thing would be very difficult pre-2.4 without a custom auth handler.

Comment: I will have to try this when I can get my hands on Apache 2.4.x - thanks!